# viewport meta tags issue on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a somewhat-responsive Bootstrap website. Above 1200px, the container is 1170px wide and below that, it scales down to 970px. Anything below that will also get the 970px version.

In my meta tags, I have this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Everything works perfectly on Desktop computers as well as on iPhone or iPad devices. However on Android based mobiles like Samsung Galaxy (where the viewport is 360x640px I believe), the website shows fine too in landscape mode, except that it is zoomed in every time a page loads. Meaning it shows fine, but the user would have to scroll left and right. The user can zoom out and then it shows full-width without having to scroll, but the next time a page loads, the same happens again.

Is there any simple way to adjust/fix this?

I tried removing the width=device-width part, but that messes with the design on iOS devices and 1px lines don't show properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
@media (whichever desired screens)
html{zoom:0.7} // this value is not calculated just an example
```

You can calculate using device width / your html width

This is has worked for me .. i need to zoom out on tablets so i added this..